# Why Lack of fit test is significant?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting

I fitted a dose-response curve and part of my data is significant for Lack-of-Fit test, but I don't understand why? If visually the model has a good adjustment. 
[image: curve fitting]

I know the Lack-of-Fit test is not a [powerful test](https://rdrr.io/cran/drc/man/modelFit.html). Can I ignore this test, what test can I do instead of lack-of-fit? How can I prove the good fit of my data, using the software R?

I provide a part of my data and the code utilized to generate the curve adjustment:

```
library(drc)

data <- structure(list(solution = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
     "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",  "B",
     "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), dose = c(0.1, 
     0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1e-04, 1e-04,  1e-04, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
     0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05 ), resp = c(40, 35, 43, 10, 10, 5, 12, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10, 0,  3, 5, 63, 63, 63, 43, 43, 43, 20, 25, 28, 15, 12, 12, 8, 3, 5 )), row.names = c(NA,
     -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))

curvefit <- drm(resp ~ dose, solution, data = data, fct = LL.4())    
modelFit(curvefit) #### LoF = 0.0004      
summary(curvefit) ## RSE = 3.43 (22 df)     
plot(curvefit) ### visually the model fit well
```

Comment: Just because there's sufficient data/little enough noise that the lack of fit test is able to distinguish between your fitted model and the conditional mean of the data doesn't mean that your model is not suitable for some purpose. Whether you really need to do anything about it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to compare the ["e" parameter of each curve](https://rstats4ag.org/dose-response-curves.html) (look at the 11.4 topic for more details), with the proven difference I can assume the organism is more sensitive to the solution I am evaluating.

Comment: The plot you have provided correctly uses the decade log of dose, that is, log10(dose), because that gives a better understanding of what the data represents. The data given to the curve-fitting software, however, is the non-log-transformed dose. If you would like to see the fit results from the "point of view" of the curve fitting software itself, and any fit statistics from that curve fitting software, make plots that do not use the log10 transform of dose.